# jqGrid - 'in' op not working for filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a simple demo that gets a "greater-than" filter working on a table of test scores. The source can be found [by clicking here](http://pastebin.com/ExkDAbsB). If you scroll down to **var myfilter**, you will see that I have one of the rules commented out.

```
var myfilter = {
    groupOp: "AND",
    rules: [
        {field: 'score', op: 'gt', data: 70},
        //{field: 'grade', op: 'in', data: [10, 11, 12]}
    ]
};
```

This rule says to only select rows for grades 10, 11, 12. However, when I uncomment this rule it doesn't work. In fact, it even breaks the table. Is this a bug, or am I going about it wrong?

To be clear, I simply want to find a way to use the **op: 'in'** feature. The jqGrid wiki on searching lists **op: 'in'** under the values for **sopt**, so there should be a way to do it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. The current implementation of *local* searching don't support `"in"` operation. It uses just `"eq"` instead.

So I would suggest you to use block with `"eq"` operations instead of `"in"`. The example from your question could be rewritten to the following:

```
var myfilter = {
    groupOp: "AND",
    rules: [
        {field: 'score', op: 'gt', data: 70},
    ],
    groups: [
        {
            groupOp: "OR",
            rules: [
                {field: 'grade', op: 'eq', data: 10}
                {field: 'grade', op: 'eq', data: 11}
                {field: 'grade', op: 'eq', data: 12}
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

See description of the full format of `filters` [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching#options).

Comment: Thanks, Oleg! Your support on these boards is really appreciated